# Bit set/clear in C?

Tags: c, embedded

How do I write to a single bit? I have a variable that is either a 1 or 0 and I want to write its value to a single bit in a 8-bit `reg` variable.

I know this will set a bit:

```
reg |= mask; // mask is (1 << pin)
```

And this will clear a bit:

```
reg &= ~mask; // mask is (1 << pin)
```

Is there a way for me to do this in one line of code, without having to determine if the value is high or low as the input?

Comment: `register` is a keyword in C. You must not use it as a name.

Comment: I made a change in the question: `register` to `reg`. It needs peer approval.

Comment: Can't see the edit queue, changed it directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming `value` is `0` or `1`:

```
REG = (REG & ~(1 << pin)) | (value << pin);
```

I use `REG` instead of `register` because as [@KerrekSB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) pointed out in OP comments, `register` is a C keyword.

The idea here is we compute a value of `REG` with the specified bit cleared and then depending on `value` we set the bit.

Comment: This actually generates branchfree code with `GCC -O2` For restricting the value to {0,1} I'd suggest to use `... | ((!!value) << pin)`

Comment: @wildplasser for the general case I think this is highly compiler dependent. On some compilers I would be afraid using logical operators  would actually *add* some branch code.

Comment: IMHO it would need loops on architectures that don't have bitshift instructions in hardware (DEC alpha didnot have them, IIRC), but the `reg = a | b;` itself does not imply a branch, obviously.

Comment: @wildpasser or MSP-430 which can bitwise shift only one bit at a time.

Comment: IIRC the first 8088 could not shift by the CX register yet. (or was it only the 6502?)

Comment: Because I'm using the MSP430 I'll test it to see if this is more expensive than branch statements.  I didn't relize I could only shift one bit at a time.  I like the solution though.  The values for `(1 << pin)` could be stored in an array to speed things up.

Comment: @tylerjw note that if `pin` is a constant, `1 << pin` will be computed at compiler time by the compiler and not by the target.

Comment: @ouah Is that still true if the code is within a function that gets called with different values of pin?

Comment: @tylerjw if `pin` is a function parameter, this no longer holds as parameters are not C constants.

Comment: @tylerjw Did you ever find out if this is more expensive  than branches ?

Comment: For me (on the msp430) this generated a bunch of machine code and the if statement with a branch generated less code.  I couldn't figure out how to get a useful benchmark of this and ended up just using the if statements in the end sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Because you tagged this with *embedded* I think the best answer is:

```
if (set)
    reg |= mask; // mask is (1 << pin)
else
    reg &= ~mask; // mask is (1 << pin)
```

(which you can wrap in a macro or inline function).  The reason being that embedded architectures like AVR have bit-set and bit-clear instructions and the cost of branching is not high compared to other instructions (as it is on a modern CPU with speculative execution).  GCC can identify the idioms in that `if` statement and produce the right instructions.  A more complex version (even if it's branchless when tested on modern x86) might not assemble to the best instructions on an embedded system.

The best way to know for sure is to disassemble the results.  You don't have to be an expert (especially in embedded environments) to evaluate the results.

Comment: for these microcontrollers, you will have to use the correct register to perform the reset and the correct one to perform the clear. Something like: `if ( set) reg_set = mask; else reg_clr = mask;`. Registers being defined as `volatile` objects, the compiler does not have the right to perform this optimization (=replacing `reg` with`reg_set / reg_clr`) itself.

Comment: Ouah gives good advise; you can't actually tell whether reg |= mask results in a bit set or a read-mofify-write, this is CPU and compiler dependant (I'd say that it is more likely to results in the later). In cases like this, always disassemble the code to see what actually happens.

Answer (score 2):

One overlooked feature of C is bit packing, which is great for embedded work. You can define a `struct` to access each bit individually.

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char bit0 : 1;
    unsigned char bit1 : 1;
    unsigned char bit2 : 1;
    unsigned char bit3 : 1;
    unsigned char bit4 : 1;
    unsigned char bit5 : 1;
    unsigned char bit6 : 1;
    unsigned char bit7 : 1;
} T_BitArray;
```

The `: 1` tells the compiler that you only want each variable to be 1 bit long. And then just access the address that your variable `reg` sits on, cast it to your bit array and then access the bits individually.

```
((T_BitArray *)&reg)->bit1 = value;
```

`&reg` is the address of your variable. `((T_BitArray *)&reg)` is the same address, but now the complier thinks of it as a `T_BitArray` address and `((T_BitArray *)&reg)->bit1` provides access to the second bit. Of course, it's best to use more descriptive names than `bit1`

Comment: +1 this is a very useful abstraction that I've seen used by embedded compiler vendors in driver code for peripherals

Comment: This is 100% non-portable and unsafe. Using bit fields is always a bad idea, particularly in embedded systems. What you call bit 7 in the above is not necessarily bit 7. It is not necessarily even allocated in the same byte as you hoped for. [More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields/6044223#6044223).

Comment: @Lundin If you disable padding, is it still bad idea?

Comment: For the most part the issues raised by @Lundin are implementation-specific. I agree with the 100% non-portable. The question remains: is your code required to be portable? A lot of my work is drivers for specific microcontrollers, where I look up how the compiler will pack bits, and it usually provides enough detail to guarantee the results I want. BUT ONLY FOR A PARTICULAR PROCESSOR!

Comment: This is a risky way to access bits in registers. It might work for one version of a compiler with one set of compiler flags, but can easily break leading to hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Through Macro we can do set resset Bit
#define set(a,n)   a|=(1<<n);
#define reset(a,n) a&=(0<<n);
//toggle bit value given by the user
#define toggle(a,n)  a^=(1<<n);

int a,n;
int main()
{
     printf("Set Reset particular Bit given by User ");
     scanf("%d %d",&a,&n);
     int b =set(a,n)   //same way we can call all the macro
     printf("%d",b);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is if you can execute a write instruction on a single bit without first reading the byte that it's in. If so, then no, you can't do that. Has nothing to do with the C language, just microprocessors don't have instructions that address single bits. Even in raw machine code, if you want to set a bit you have to read the byte it's in, change the bit, then write it back. There's just no other way to do it.

Comment: actually for GPIO a lot of microcontrollers have special registers that allow you to set or clear bits without the need to perform a read first.

Comment: Yeah it's called bit-banding

Comment: Cool. I suspect that the OP is asking about general-purpose RAM, though.

Comment: On ARM Cortex-M bit-banding and possible on on-chip RAM *and* peripheral registers.

Comment: Shan't downvote, but there **is** another way - many micros have SET and CLEAR registers for ports, I've posted it as an answer. OP is tagged [embedded] so I'll assume it's applicable.

Comment: I'm using this on a GPIO port on a msp430 target.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [how do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c/11036329) and I'll repost my answer too as no-one's mentioned SET and CLEAR registers yet:

> As this is tagged "embedded" I'll assume you're using a microcontroller. All of the above suggestions are valid & work (read-modify-write, unions, structs, etc.).
>
> However, during a bout of oscilloscope-based debugging I was amazed to find that these methods have a considerable overhead in CPU cycles compared to writing a value directly to the micro's PORTnSET / PORTnCLEAR registers which makes a real difference where there are tight loops / high-frequency ISR's toggling pins.
>
> For those unfamiliar: In my example, the micro has a general pin-state register PORTn which reflects the output pins, so doing PORTn |= BIT_TO_SET results in a read-modify-write to that register.
>
> However, the PORTnSET / PORTnCLEAR registers take a '1' to mean "please make this bit 1" (SET) or "please make this bit zero" (CLEAR) and a '0' to mean "leave the pin alone". so, you end up with two port addresses depending whether you're setting or clearing the bit (not always convenient) but a much faster reaction and smaller assembled code.