# Bit fields portability

Tags: c, portability, bit-fields

I read [here](http://www.indiabix.com/technical/c/bits-and-bytes/) that bit fields are not portable. Does that mean that the code below that defines bit fields (code taken from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm)) could not compile on certain machines?

If so, then why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* define simple structure */
struct
{
  unsigned int widthValidated;
  unsigned int heightValidated;
} status1;

/* define a structure with bit fields */
struct
{
  unsigned int widthValidated : 1;
  unsigned int heightValidated : 1;
} status2;

int main( )
{
   printf( "Memory size occupied by status1 : %d\n", sizeof(status1));
   printf( "Memory size occupied by status2 : %d\n", sizeof(status2));

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Bit fields are portable, in the sense that they are a part of the C language as specified in the standard ([C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.7.2.1). Any compiler that fails to recognise code that uses bitfields is not standard-compliant. There's also nothing really questionable about your example, since all it does is have bitfields present.

What they probably mean is that the fields themselves may be packed unpredictably in location and order (allowed by the standard, previous ref. paragraph 11). This means that a struct with e.g. four bitfields of size 4, 12, 13 and 3 does not necessarily take up 32 bits and they won't necessarily be placed within the struct in that order; the compiler can place them where it likes. This means that the struct cannot be treated as an actual component-wise representation of an underlying binary object.

In contrast, bitmasks applied manually to integers exist exactly where you put them. If you define masks that mask out the first 4 bits, second 12 bits, etc. of an unsigned integer, the "fields" will actually apply to the bits, in order and in position (assuming you know the endianness, anyway). This makes the representation compiler-independent.

i.e. they are portable, but what they do may not necessarily be exactly what a person actually wanting to manipulate individual bits may need.

Comment: Is this only a theoretical limitation of bitfields or also a practical one? i.e. do different GCC versions that are somewhat current compile bitfields as different memory layouts? What about GCC vs Clang vs others?

Comment: Fitting bitfields into larger types is implementation specific, so cannot be relied upon.  I had a problem with this in a networking library where it was using bitfields to specify flags in the packet header, then sending the underlying binary representation. If the receiver was not compiled with the same compiler then there was no guarantee that the receiver would interpret the binary to the same bitfield values, and indeed when the code went cross-platform the protocol headers were considered corrupt. Bit-masks fixed this.

Answer (score 13):

Bit fields are standard language feature. They will compile in all C compilers. They are portable in that sense of the term. Your code is well-formed and will compile in all C compilers as well.

Statements like "bit-fields are not portable" usually mean that the physical layout of bit-fields in memory might differ from implementation to implementation (i.e. from one compiler to another). You might get different output from your program, if compiled on different implementations. But the the difference in program's behavior can only occur if (and when) your code depends on the memory layout of objects with bit-fields (e.g. if you measure their size, as you do in your program).

In other words, to say that "bit-fields are not portable" is pretty much the same thing as to say that type `int` is "not portable" just because it can have different size on different platforms or use different endianness in its internal representation.

Answer (score 3):

An `int` is required to be at least 16 bits in C. Therefore, if you wish to use bit-fields in maximally portable code, you cannot have a bit-field that occupies more than 16 bits.

C.11 §6.7.2.1¶5:

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type.

C.11 §5.4.2.1¶1:

> — maximum value for an object of type `int`
>   `INT_MAX +32767 //` 2<sup>15</sup> − 1
>   — maximum value for an object of type `unsigned int`
>   `UINT_MAX 65535 //` 2<sup>16</sup> − 1

Comment: Even then, you don't know which bits the compiler will choose to use for which bit-fields when packing the bit-fields into that 16-bits. It could vary based on the CPU endian, optimizations, or even just an arbitrary choice made by the compiler writer.

Comment: @jtchitty: All true, but does not affect the portability of the code in the OP, nor do your objections negate the possibility of writing a maximally portable C program using bit-fields.

Comment: Agreed. The code in the OP is portable code, in the sense that it compiles and runs correctly on any standard-compliant C compiler. Comments regarding "non-portability" of bit fields generally have to do with the consistency of the bit-packing. The bit packing will vary, so code that depends on the bit packing behaviour (e.g., if casting the bit fields to an array of bytes or integers for network transmission) will not be portable, regardless of what size of integer is used for the bit fields.

Comment: @jtchitty: While it is good to remind users of this, that point had already been made when I authored my answer. I was adding a contribution that had not yet been made.

Comment: So, you are saying that, to be portable, any given single bit-field within a struct must not be larger than 16 bits. That is one thing that does indeed affect portability. There are others too, such as not using 'int' without 'signed' or 'unsigned' (because signed-ness of an int bit-field is implementation-defined) and using only integers or _Bool. Perhaps you should expand your answer? Regardless, I think it's best to recommend that people just avoid bit-fields, because of all the implementation-defined behaviour surrounding this feature.

Comment: @jtchitty: What you have mentioned is already stated in the section of the C standard quoted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I work mainly in the embedded field and when you need to work with hardware registers and bit flags, bit fields take away a lot of the tedious bit fiddling.

I do not understand the big push against bit fields, each time referring to the standard and how you should roll your own flags because that is more portable; it is error prone and ugly.

I do understand the concept and advantages of bitbanding, but that is very microcontroller specific.

Rather than a standard that enforces an order, I rather value **consistency** and especially **asserting** your assumptions are correct. So if you have a certain use for bit fields, go ahead and check that your layout is corresponding to the truth. E.g.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdalign.h>

typedef struct Foo_t {
  union {
    struct {
      uint16_t size  : 9;
      uint16_t flag  : 1;
      uint16_t type  : 3;
      uint16_t prop  : 3;
    };
    uint16_t   raw;
  };
} Foo_t;

static void checkbits(void) {

  Foo_t Foo;

  assert(sizeof(Foo_t)  == sizeof(uint16_t));
  assert(alignof(Foo_t) == sizeof(uint16_t));
  
  Foo.size = 365;
  
  assert((Foo.raw & 0b111111111) == Foo.size);

  Foo.prop = 0b110;
  Foo.type = 0b001;

  assert(((Foo.raw & 0xE000) >> 13) == Foo.prop);
  assert(((Foo.raw & 0x1C00) >> 10) == Foo.type);

  // ... rest to do as an exercise ...

}
```

NOTE: You do use a assert() a lot in your code, do you?

Also note the use of the stdint types; never use the native types directly for embedded programming.

Call the checkbits() function and you are good to go; if on one system with a certain compiler, the assumptions don't hold, use macros and a rearranged struct until the raw format is OK again.

Note in the checkbits() code how fiddly it is to flesh out the individual parts for checking. You do that tedious job once, in your checking routine, you double check, and then you are as free as a fiddle in the rest of your code.

Comment: Those asserts could and should be `static_assert` so you don't have to call them at run-time.  (In C11, `#include <assert.h>` for the `#define static_assert _Static_assert`).  Or in C23, `static_assert` is itself a keyword and `_Static_assert` is deprecated.  (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert)