# Size of a struct containing bitfields defined with different types

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

I have a struct that contains bitfields with different sizes. Some of the bitfields are only 1 bit and some of them are 32 bit wide. I will fill this struct with a buffer received from a serial communication. So I planned to define them in bitfields then use `memcpy` to fill the buffer with the received packet.

This is my struct definition:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct{

    uint32_t    variable1;          //32 bit
    uint16_t    variable2:16;       //16 bit
    uint32_t    variable3:18;       //18 bit
    uint32_t    variable4:10;       //10 bit
    uint32_t    variable5:4;        //4 bit
    uint8_t     variable6;          //8 bit
    uint8_t     variable7:7;        //7 bit
    uint8_t     variable8:1;        //1 bit
    uint8_t     variable9:6;        //6 bit
    uint8_t     variable10:6;       //6 bit
    uint8_t     variable11:7;       //7 bit
    uint8_t     variable12:5;       //5 bit

}error_driver_t;            //Total length should be 15 bytes (120 bit)
#pragma pack(pop)

printf("\r\nSize of error_driver_t: %d\r\n\r\n", sizeof(demoErrorDriver));    //Expected 15, Resulted 20
```

The serial packet is 15 bytes so I expect this struct to be 15 bytes long too to use the `memcpy` properly. But when I get the `sizeof(error_driver_t)`, I get 20.

I'm confused about how to use the bitfields when I have both small and bigger types in the same struct.

Comment: I tried it (compiled with clang) and got 15. I did have to change `demoErrorDriver` to `error_driver_t` in the `sizeof`.

Comment: @user3386109 I also tried that but it's still 20

Comment: In addition to what @kiranBiradar said, as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c) answer even the order in which the variables is declared can make the result of ```sizeof``` change drastically

Comment: @kiranBiradarI thought pragma pack would eliminate padding here to 1 byte?

Comment: @JohnSmith I can not change the order because the order is decided by another device which is sending me the 15 bytes packet over the serial communication.

Comment: @abdullahcinar thing is, you can't rely on the struct to have an exact ```sizeof``` of 15 bytes even if that's what is contained in it. You could use a bit mask to get only the bits you want from the packet to put in each variable.

Comment: Bitfields are not well defined by the C specification. If all of the types were `uint32_t`, you might have a chance, but `variable2` and `variable6` prevent you from doing that. So I think you're stuck with defining the `struct` without bitfields, and then extract fields with masking and shifting.

Comment: Yes, I think parsing the received packet with masking and shifting is the safest solution. But I just wondered if there is a strict rule I'm missing here.

Comment: `uint32_t    variable1;          //32 bit
    uint16_t    variable2:16;       //16 bit
    uint32_t    variable3:18;       //18 bit` - usually that does not work. Make all variables have the same type. What compiler are you using? The best solution: don't use bitfields. Use masks.

Comment: I'm using GNU GCC Compiler. If I make all the variables have the same type, it even increases the size. So I tried this.

Comment: @user3386109 *defining the `struct` without bitfields, and then extract fields with masking and shifting*  That is the **only** portable, reliable way to set/read bits in a precise order.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345691/bit-fields-portability.  `#pragma pack` is also highly non-portable and can even [produce code that won't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568432/is-gccs-attribute-packed-pragma-pack-unsafe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be certain that a struct will have the exact `sizeof` equal to the sum of the size of the variables contained in it. This is influenced by many factors including struct padding, what pragma pack you are using, which compiler you are using and even in which order your variables are in the `struct` as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c) answer to a similar question.

In addition to this the C standard says that:

> Multiple adjacent bit fields are usually packed together (although this behavior is implementation-defined)

So you can't be certain that two different variables will occupy exactly the sum of their bitfields either.

All in all your best best would be to use multiple bitmasks and/or bit shifts to get the values you need from the packet.

Comment: Then, can we say that we should use bitfields only when we are filling the struct by assigning the elements one by one instead of raw copying?

Comment: @abdullahcinar generally speaking yes, you should be able to raw copy a value to a single bitfield variable safely if the bitfield is big enough but don't quote me on that as i haven't tested it.

Comment: Yes, I can raw copy a value to a single bitfield but I can not raw copy to a single struct containing bitfields.

Comment: working with single bits is always finicky, you could try to have the struct occupy exactly 15 bytes but even if you succeed you are not guaranteed that it will be the same on a different compiler or platform