# MISRA ERROR: field type should be int, unsigned int or signed int

Tags: c, misra, pc-lint

I have used following code in my program and while running PC-Lint it throws following error:
Multiple markers at this line
    - (lint:46) field type should be int, unsigned int or signed int [MISRA 2004 Rule 6.4, required]
    - (lint:960) Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 6.4, Bit field must be explicitly signed int or 
     unsigned int

```
typedef struct{
  boolean ch8 :1;
  boolean Ch7 :1;
  boolean Ch6 :1;
  boolean Ch5 :1;
  boolean Ch4 :1;
  boolean Ch3 :1;
  boolean Ch2 :1;
  boolean Ch1 :1;
} Channel;
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Well, what's `boolean`? There's no type `boolean` in C.

Comment: Most likely, your compiler defines boolean to be a 1 byte character type. Solve this by never using bit-fields in any situation, they are dangerous, non-portable and 100% superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it like this:

```
typedef struct{
  unsigned int ch8 :1;
  unsigned int Ch7 :1;
  unsigned int Ch6 :1;
  unsigned int Ch5 :1;
  unsigned int Ch4 :1;
  unsigned int Ch3 :1;
  unsigned int Ch2 :1;
  unsigned int Ch1 :1;
} Channel;
```

The only types a bitfield accepts, are integer types.

Comment: Please note that the bits may end up in pretty much any random way when you do this. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields/6044223#6044223).

Answer (score 0):

MISRA-C:2004 is compatible with C:90 which does not have a `boolean` type.

To be perfectly compliant bit-fields have to be `unsigned int` or `signed int`

Alternatively, you can document a Deviation (to Rule 1.1) to permit the use of the C99 boolean type - the rationale would be straightforward, as the corresponding MISRA C:2012 Rule (R 6.1) permits the use of boolean for bit fields.

[Please note Profile disclaimer]

Comment: Given: `struct { bool flag:1; uint8_t x:7; } foo;` would the fields be eligible to be placed in the same byte of storage?  Would `foo.flag = 2;` set the value to a zero or non-zero value?  The MISRA rules are supposed to promote portability, but I don't know that implementations would treat the above consistently.

Comment: Putting the value 2 into a 1 bit sized variable is an over-flow condition whether bool is signed or unsigned.  That is a basic coding error!  Instinct suggests that the value should be 0 (the LSB is zero)

Comment: Storing any non-zero value into a C99 `bool` is equivalent to storing the value 1; I don't know any advantage that type would have over any other if one weren't going to take advantage of that.

Comment: I wouldn't make that assumption - especially if you are using bit fields.

Comment: I wouldn't either, but I can't think of any other reason to use `bool` as a bit-field type, I would be loath to assume that someone who did so wasn't relying upon such behavior.  Personally, I think C99 would be better off if reading a `bool` to which a value other than 0 or 1 had been stored would yield an Unspecified result (avoiding the need to have the compiler generate code to coerce values that a programmer knew would always be 0 or 1).

Comment: I agree with you. The C99 implementation of _Bool is so broken...  I suspect `bool x:1 = 2` and `bool x:1 = (bool)(2)` *may* yield differing results!