# unions as bit fields inside structures

Tags: c, unions, bit-fields

I have the following:

```
typedef enum {
green = 0;
orange = 1;
red = 2;
} color;

typedef enum {
proceed = 0;
prepare = 1;
stop = 2;
} state;

typedef union {
color a;
state b;
uint8_t reserved;
} status;

typedef struct {

u32 m : 8;
u32 n : 8;
status var : 8;
u32 res : 8;

} info;
```

I am seeing a compilation error when I define a structure variable:

error: bit-field 'var' has invalid type.

I would like to pack the structure within the 4 bytes, and make the union of enums as a bit field. Is this possible?

Comment: A bit-field must have an integer type (not an union)

Comment: What are you trying with `struct var : 8;`?

Comment: [Just don't use bit fields at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields/6044223#6044223).

Comment: ok, so you're saying I use "u32 var : 8" and typecast it to enum each time I want to reference its members? Is that the only way?

Answer (score 3):

Bit fields are defined and restricted only to data types `int`, `signed int`, `unsigned int` but nit for `union` type as per `C89` or `C90` standard. [Bit Field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), applies both for C/C++, with `_Bool` type defined in `C99`

Comment: ok, so you're saying I use "u32 var : 8" and typecast it to enum each time I want to reference its members? Is that the only way?

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the layout you want, best to ask for it as directly as possible. Probably something like:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t m;
    uint8_t n;
    uint8_t var;
    uint8_t res;
} info;
```

Use an explicitly sized type if you want a particular size. An `enum` type or union containing a member of `enum` type is allowed to be (at least) the same size as `int`, so your desire for this specific layout rules that out.