# C bit field/array

Tags: c, bit-fields

I have to do a project for school. But I got stuck right at the beginning.

I have to define type for bitfield. It isn't a problem, it would look like this:

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned flag1 : 1;
   unsigned flag2 : 1;
}BitArray;
```

But next task is to do set of macros for working with bitfield. One of them is:

```
create(field_name,size) /* defines and initializes bitfield */
```

The question is how can I typedef bitfield so I could change number of its members later?

Second method that came to my mind is to use bool array. But again, how can I typedef bool array? At frist I tried:

```
typedef bool BitArray[]; //new identifier BitArray for bool array
BitArray Array[5];      //new BitArray variable Array - this line would be in the macro mentioned above
```

It didn't take me a long time to realise that it won't work. However I can do:

```
typedef bool BitArray;
BitArray Array[5];
```

But it just ranames identifier for bool.

I hope my post makes sense and thank you for any advise you can give.

Comment: Note:in C you cant have array of bits. the bool type is defined as an int or short int anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is how can I typedef bitfield so I could change number of its members later?

That's what the `typedef struct ... BitArray` does. No need for additional types.

A bool array will most likely not compile into bit-wise code, it will likely compile into an array of bytes, which is not what you want.

In addition, it is a very bad idea to hide arrays or pointers behind typedefs, so that they don't look like arrays or pointers no longer.

---

Some recommendations:

> I have to define type for bitfield

[I would not recommend to use bit fields for any purpose what-so-ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields/6044223#6044223). You should question your teacher why they are teaching you to use dangerous and poorly specified parts of the C language.

> But next task is to do set of macros for working with bitfield

You should ask your teacher why they teach you to use function-like macros and not proper functions. Using a function-like macro might be the worst thing you can ever do in C: they are dangerous, they are unreadable, they are hard to debug, they are hard to maintain.

Combining function-like macros mixed with bit-fields seems like a *really* stupid idea, but of course that is just my personal opinion. The safe and 100% portable way is to use bit-wise operators with masks on byte-level variables, such as:

```
uint8_t my_var=0;
my_var |= 0x80; // set msb, bit 7
my_var &= ~0x80; // clear msb, bit 7
```

Answer (score 1):

In C you can declare a typedef only for fixed-size array, like this:

```
typedef bool bitset8[8]; // 8 is constant expression
bitset8 bs8;
bs8[0] = true;
```

I don't quite understand how exactly `create` macro from your post is going to be used, but if you need to dynamically change number of fields you have to use malloc'ed objects *ANYWAY*, so the declaration of `BitArray` struct should contain a pointer to let's say `unsigned char` (that is a pointer to byte array essentially). The content of the array should be managed by separate functions, that may be called from macros (though there is no real need in them).