# Bit Fields in C

Tags: c, int, hex, bit-fields, negative-number

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct test 
{
   int x: 2;
   int y: 2;
};
int main()
{
   test t;
   t.x = -1;
   printf("%d", t.x);
   return 0;
}
```

This snippet prints `-1` which I can understand,

If the same code, `%d`is replaced with `%x` format specifier like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct test 
{
   int x: 2;
   int y: 2;
};
int main()
{
   test t;
   t.x = -1;
   printf("%x", t.x);
   return 0;
}
```

The output becomes `ffffffff`.

Please explain why this is the case.

Comment: Both the snippets are same.....(edited) not any more. :-)

Comment: What do you think is the representation of -1?

Comment: The bit fields are irrelevant - you will get the same result if you pass `-1` to `printf` in place of `t.x`.

Comment: @rakeb.void Somebody having an "angry day". I wrote the only answer that explains _why_ the bit field turns into an int and got down voted too, no reason given...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%x` prints the hex representation of the value of the given argument. The two's complement representation of `-1`, in hex, gives you that `ffffffff`.

<sup>FWIW: This outcome is not particularly related to use of bit-filed variable here, as `printf()` is a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

When you pass your bit field to `printf`, a function with variable number of arguments, the value undergoes a conversion to `int`. Even though the value has only two bits, its binary value of `11` means `-1` in two's complement representation, so the value gets sign-extended into an integer `-1` when it is sent to `printf`. This is `0xffffffff` in hex representation on 32-bit systems.

If you would like to see only two bits printed as hex, make your bit field unsigned. This will ensure that no sign extension would be performed before printing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct test 
{
   unsigned int x: 2;
   unsigned int y: 2;
};
int main()
{
   struct test t;
   t.x = -1;
   printf("%x", t.x);
   return 0;
}
```

This prints 3 ([demo](http://ideone.com/9MNAfb)).

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with bit fields as such. It happens because of an obscure rule in C called *the default argument promotions*:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does not include a prototype, **the integer promotions are performed on
>   each argument**, and arguments that have type float are promoted to
>   double. These are called the default argument promotions.

(Emphasis mine) And this rule also applies to variadic functions like printf:

> The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter.
>   The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

So your bit field is integer promoted to type `int` before printf even starts interpreting it. The sign is preserved, so what you are seeing is the hex representation of a two's complement `int` containing the value -1.

As a side note, I would not recommend you to use bit fields at all, as their behavior is poorly specified and they are completely non-portable. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields/6044223#6044223).

Answer (score 1):

Your system (and almost all) systems stores negative numbers in 2's complement form. `-1` is represented as `FFH` in 8-bit 2's complement form.

What you are observing is sign extended 2's complement of '-1'.

Answer (score 1):

`%x` means that `printf` will output its value in hexadecimal format. Now, the question is why the output of `-1` is looks like `ffffffff` (`0xffffffff`).

`1 byte` means `8 bits`, and in hexadecimal, you can fit up to `f` in `4 bits`. So `1 byte` can hold maximum value of `ff` in hexadecimal.

So,

```
Bytes       Hex            Bin
1 byte      ff             11111111
4 byte      ff ff ff ff    11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Now, `-1` is representative as [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), means it is a negative number of `1`.

```
toggle:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (to fit in 4 byte)
toggle:   11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
+1    :                                    +1
----------------------------------------------
value :   11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
hex   :   ff       ff       ff       ff
```

So, `0xffffffff` is tows complements representation of `-1`. No magic.