# Mixing bitfields in structures

Tags: c, bit-fields

Hanging on geeksforgeeks about bitfields, found this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    unsigned int x;
    long int y : 33;
    unsigned int z;
};

int main() {
    struct test t;
    unsigned int *ptr1 = &t.x;
    unsigned int *ptr2 = &t.z;
    printf("%d", ptr2 - ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

As result, output is 4. But why? x occupies 4 bytes, y - 8, and z - 4. Difference in addresses x and z must be 8?

Comment: The difference between two pointers is not counted in bytes, but in whatever type the pointers point to. Moreover, `type` is aligned to the alignment of the most aligned member (probably `long int`), and `&test.x == &test`, so if `sizeof(unsigned) != sizeof(long int)`, there is an alignment gap (padding) between `test.x` and `test.y`, provided the implementation even accepts bitfields of type `long int`.

Comment: I keep hearing about this "geekforgeeks" in every post that contains awful, poorly-specified behavior, nonsense code. I really think you should avoid that site, it doesn't quite seem like they know what they are talking about there.

Comment: Lundin: Maybe I can agree, I've found it just couple of days ago... But anyway, this tricky "spherical horse in a vacuum" example, struggled me:)

Comment: @artsin The correct term is spherical cow.

Comment: @artsin The code was written by a spherical horse? The only thing to learn from this code is that bit-fields should be avoided entirely. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields/6044223#6044223) for example.

Comment: It think it speaks for itself that [this post](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scansets-in-c/) on geeksforgeeks for example, warns about using gets, and then uses various variations of `scanf("%s")` without specifying maximum field width. I don't think content is reviewed too well over there.

Comment: @Lundin: I don't see how one'd conclude that "bit-fields should be avoided entirely" from that. Most problems with bit-fields arise from bizarre misguided attempts to force the compiler to allocate bit-fields in accordance with some external layout specification. True, bit-fields don't work well for that purpose. But why would anyone even try to use them for that purpose? This is not what bit-fields are for.

Comment: @AnT That's the problem, _everyone_ who use them use them to map a memory specific layout: hardware registers, data packets etc. _Nobody_ uses them for what they could actually be safely used as, like a collection of boolean flags, storing chunks of small data etc. Bit-fields is a 100% superfluous feature anyway, there is never a reason to use them anywhere, even in the very rare cases when they are safe to use.

Comment: @Lundin: I believe your experience is rather lopsided. Mine is quite different: I see a lot of people use bit-fields correctly, in accordance with their native purpose, i.e. to save memory. Why you call that native purpose "superfluous" is completely unclear to me. "Never a reason", really? There's never a reason to save memory these days?

Comment: Hey, guys, I have one notice for this conversation. I am fully agreed with statements, that usage of bitfields with such way is bad idea. But I think, it is useful, due to a) It is necessary to know, that you DO NOT NEED to do, and b) such kind of questions I think happens on interviews (for which I want to prepare by the way...) Of course, IMHO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code has no determinable behavior. It is impossible to predict any outcome of it without a very specific compiler in mind.

It contains the following implementation-defined behavior (quotes from Annex J of the standard):

> — Whether a ‘‘plain’’ int bit-field is treated as a signed int
>   bit-field or as an unsigned int bit-field (6.7.2, 6.7.2.1).
>
> — Allowable bit-field types other than _Bool, signed int, and unsigned
>   int (6.7.2.1).
>
> — Whether a bit-field can straddle a storage-unit boundary (6.7.2.1).
>
> — The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (6.7.2.1).
>
> — The alignment of non-bit-field members of structures (6.7.2.1). This
>   should present no problem unless binary data written by one
>   implementation is read by another.

The second remark also implies that the compiler must have a non-standard extension.

On top of that, the code also depends on endianess and you cannot know which bits in the bit-field that are the MSB and LSB.

Comment: More relevant: C11 draft standard `6.5.6 Additive operators, Section 9 When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;[...]`. Though `6.5.8 Relational operators, Section 5 [...] If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure[...]` makes it *likely* no real implementation is going to fail this code.

Comment: Also, `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)` are also implementation defined. We can see here this code was compiled with a 64-bit non-MSVC compiler because `sizeof(long)` is 8. With MSVC or 32-bit compilers, `sizeof(long)` is 4.

Comment: @EOF Yes, I am sure one could write a full essay about how this code could/will go wrong. Just don't write such nonsense code and there will be no problems.