Bitfield type in C - particularly its availability in XCODE
I've encountered the following couple of snippets of code in a source hive (ok, it's Nethack) that are causing me trouble regarding Bitfields and what appears to be some reflection going on.
Specific error is that BITFIELD is not recognized in XCODE, error comes up on the Bitfield definitions in the Struct. Is there a different way that would be largely compatible available that I'm not finding?
I used to be a professional C++ programmer a decade ago and this isn't how I'd do things at all.
//Definition - It appears that BITFIELDS is defined by default. This code snippets are verified from the nethack source globals.h
    #ifdef BITFIELDS /* Force overriding Bitfields */
    #define Bitfield(x, n) unsigned x : n
    #else
    #define Bitfield(x, n) uchar x
    #endif

//Usage Snippet: from objclass.h
    struct objclass {
    short oc_descr_idx;             /* description when name unknown */
    char *oc_uname;                 /* called by user */
    oc_name_known Bitfield(oc_name_known, 1);     /* discovered */
    Bitfield(oc_merge, 1);          /* merge otherwise equal objects */ /*Reflection?*/
    Bitfield(oc_uses_known, 1);     /* obj->known affects full description;
                                       otherwise, obj->dknown and obj->bknown
                                       tell all, and obj->known should always
                                       be set for proper merging behavior. */
    };

I tried to compile the Nethack source

Post the exact error.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". We have [edit]ed to correct formatting flaws to make it readable. Would you mind to add a link to the source of the code snippet, please? It looks as if there is a copy error or typo.

Also note, that this code is not standard, so not every compiler is going to support it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406914/mixing-bitfields-in-structures

This question was forwarded here from the staging ground where several comments were made requesting more information and detail.  Can you please [edit] your question to provide that information?

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

The line oc_name_known Bitfield(oc_name_known, 1); expands to oc_name_known unsigned oc_name_known : 1; which is "nonsense".  Alternatively, it expands to oc_name_known uchar oc_name_known;, which is similarly "nonsense".  Remove the oc_name_known before the macro.

I tried your suggestion, Jonathan. I get an "identifier expected" error.

Right now, I gutted the nonsensical macro definition and low - I have access to regular Bitfield. I'm trying to just delete all the semi colons now and see what happens.

I just saw the comment about being used with a struct. I'll explore that tomorrow. Thanks

In addition to bit-fields being poorly standardized, this use of macros is frowned upon, since the only thing achieved with the macro is to make the code less readable. A C programmer is supposed to know what unsigned x : n means but they have no idea what the secret macro language Bitfield(oc_merge, 1); means.

A quick web search for "nethack objclass.h" revealed that the file (of version 3.6.1) has a different content than the snippet you show us. Please [edit] your question to add a link to the source you use. Even better, make sure that your source is not messed up.

This version is 3.6.7. 3.7.3 is current. I'll look at the earlier version and see how they're accomplishing this, thank you. I'll add a link to the source I'm using later.

I also had 3.6.2 on my box here and noticed that this section of code is going through a lot of changes recently. I may drop back a few more versions to try to find more success.

The issue is somewhat moot. I discovered an official binary of 3.6.1 which works well enough. I'm going to grab the 3.6.1 source now, which I assume there's evidence shown here that it might work better. Bit of time to work on this each day.

@Barmar - I call this one compete. The code I'm trying to understand is generally agreed to be almost intentionally obfuscated, the results of which are nonsense, to boot.

@GusIverson Why are you responding to me? I deleted my comment when someone corrected my misreading of the code.

Sorry, I thought you promoted it out of staging. I'm new here
