# Struct and bitfield member ordering

Tags: c++, c

Is the order of members in a) in a struct b) in a bitfield guaruanteed?
In other words, given a certain member of a struct or a bitfield, am I guaranteed that its offset from the beginning of the struct/bitfield will be no less than the sum of the sizes of the members that preceded it?

To give an example:

```
struct S{
   char a[N];
   unsigned b : M;
   char c : O;  
};
```

Will the offset of c be at least `sizeof(a)+sizeof(b)`?

Comment: No. There is also alignment involved.

Comment: @Pyjong that's why it says "no less"

Comment: @Mat That's an awful "duplicate". Bit-fields are not structs! While structs guarantee an order of allocation, bit-fields do not guarantee where their bits end up. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields) is a better duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

C++ standard:

Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class declared without an intervening access-specifier are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object.