# VStudio c++ alignment of bitfield in union

Tags: c++, c, bit-fields

In VStudio 2010, I'm trying to create a union to access a 2-byte value conveniently:

```
#pragma pack(push,1) // disable padding
typedef struct {
    uint8_t r:3;
    uint8_t g:3;
    uint8_t b:3;
}tsRgb;

typedef union {
    uint16_t raw;
    tsRgb rgb; 
}tPixelData;
#pragma pack(pop)

int main(){
    tPixelData pixel;
    pixel.raw = 0xABE5;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting to see pixel.r = 5, pixel.g = 4, pixel.b = 7.
the r and g are ok, but the b is 3.

What am I doing wrong? I assume I'm not alligning the bits correctly?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields/6044223#6044223

Comment: The standard guarantees almost nothing about bitfields. And only types `((un)signed) int` and `_Bool` are guaranteed.

Comment: downvoter please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third field will be in a separate byte.

In VC++ the bitfields do not cross the boundaries of the underlying type. When you have used 3+3 bits there are only 2 left, so the next field will use 3 bits from a fresh byte.

It might work better if you use `uint16_t` instead of `uint8_t`.

"Disable padding" works on the byte level, not on the bit level.

Comment: *The bitfields do not cross the boundaries of the underlying type*  That is implementation-defined.  While they may not cross boundaries in the VStudio implementation the OP is using, bit-fields very well can cross the boundaries of the underlying storage units.  Bit-fields are *extremely* implementation-dependent and *extremely* non-portable.

Comment: @Andrew - Ok, I added a clarification that the answer is for the system the OP is using.

Answer (score 3):

Using bit-fields is as you want to is fundamentally problematic.  Per [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**, paragraph 11 (since your question is also tagged C):

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large
> enough to hold a bit- field.  If enough space remains, a bit-field
> that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be
> packed into adjacent bits of the same unit.  If insufficient space
> remains, whether  a  bit-field  that  does  not  fit  is  put  into
> the  next  unit  or  overlaps  adjacent  units  is
> implementation-defined.  The order of allocation of bit-fields within
> a unit (high-order to low-order  or  low-order  to  high-order)  is
> implementation-defined.  The  alignment  of  the addressable storage
> unit is unspecified.

The layout and alignment of the bits in a bit-field are all implementation-defined.  Fields may or may not cross storage unit boundaries, they may be stored in any order.

They're not portable at all.

Comment: They are not a portable way of matching some on-the-wire bit format.  They *are* a portable way of reducing the memory consumption of a struct (and that is all they should be used for.)