# Linking struct/union member to another struct/union member

Tags: c

I am somewhat new to C in regards to structures, unions and bitfields and need help. Below is the SLPH_CONTROL which will "control" the bits in the destination of DRVCONF0 and DRVCONF1. After the code snippet I will explain what I need.

```
/* SLPH_CONTROL **********************************************/

typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned int SH0_BIT0 :1;
        unsigned int SH0_BIT1 :1;
    };
    uint8 SLPH_CONTROL_byte;
} SLPH_CONTROL;

SLPH_CONTROL my_SLPH_CONTROL;

/* DRVCONF0 **********************************************/

typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned int DF0_BIT0 :1;
        unsigned int DF0_BIT1 :1;
        unsigned int DF0_BIT2 :1;
        unsigned int DF0_BIT3 :1;
        unsigned int DF0_BIT4 :1;
    };
    uint8 DRVCONF0_byte;
} DRVCONF0;

DRVCONF0 my_DRVCONF0;

/* DRVCONF0 **********************************************/

typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned int DF1_BIT0 :1;
        unsigned int DF1_BIT1 :1;
        unsigned int DF1_BIT2 :1;
        unsigned int DF1_BIT3 :1;
        unsigned int DF1_BIT4 :1;
    };
    uint8 DRVCONF1_byte;
} DRVCONF1;

DRVCONF1 my_DRVCONF1;
```

Now with the code above I want to link or copy data from and to like so:

```
SH0_BIT0:1 to DF0_BIT4:1;
SH1_BIT1:1 to DF1_BIT0:1;
```

Is there a way to do this? I am really lost and looked everywhere online for a solution to this. Any suggestions are welcome!!!

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: The only way to do that would be with a couple of assignment statements. Changes to the `SH0` bits cannot be automagically reflected in the corresponding `DFx` bits. And there is no way to create a pointer to a bitfield.

Comment: If you are by any chance using bitfields as a map to individual register bits, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976147/cast-char-to-a-bit-field-entry-of-4-bits#comment71130153_41976147

Comment: `my_SLPH_CONTROL.SH0_BIT0 = my_DRVCONF1.DF0_BIT4;` etc.. Put it in a function that takes pointers to unions as arguments.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. I did what you mentioned 2501 which is:

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. 2501: I did this before I posted but did not think to put it in a function. How do you recommend I put this in a function 2501? my_SLPH_CONTROL.SH0_BIT0 = my_DRVCONF1.DF0_BIT4; yes the naming scheme is atrocious but wanted to throw something together quickly to test an idea before implementing it. This is for an embedded microcontroller application using GCC C99...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is possible on special embedded H/W (I don't know) but not on a regular PC with standard C.

Bit fields describe individual bits in one or more consecutive bytes. Actually, bytes are addressable but bits are not. The read/write access to bits is internally solved by bit-wise operations (like in C expressed with `&`, `|`, `^`, `~`).

`my_DRVCONF0` and `my_DRVCONF1` are individual variables in your sample. Thus, it's even not granted that they will be allocated/stored in consecutive memory. (They definitely will not if some kind of word-alignment is enabled.)

You probably have to make the control more sophisticated (e.g. providing pairs of address and bit index) to do what's intended.