# I need to write a C program that uses a Union structure to set the bits of an int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Here are the instructions:

Define a union data struct WORD_T for a uint16_t integer so that a value can be assigned to a WORD_T integer in three ways:
(1) To assign the value to each bit of the integer,
(2) To assign the value to each byte of the integer,
(3) To assign the value to the integer directly.

I know I need to do something different with that first struct, but I'm pretty lost in general. Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define BIT(n) (1 << n)
#define BIT_SET(var, mask) (n |= (mask) )
#define BIT_CLEAR(var, mask) (n &= ~(mask) )
#define BIT_FLIP(var, mask) (n ^= (mask) )

union WORD_T{
    struct{
        uint16_t integerVar:16

    };
    struct{
        unsigned bit1:0;
        unsigned bit2:0;
        unsigned bit3:0;
        unsigned bit4:0;
        unsigned bit5:0;
        unsigned bit6:0;
        unsigned bit7:0;
        unsigned bit8:0;
        unsigned bit9:0;
        unsigned bit10:0;
        unsigned bit11:0;
        unsigned bit12:0;
        unsigned bit13:0;
        unsigned bit14:0;
        unsigned bit15:0;
        unsigned bit16:0;
    };

    void setIndividualBit(unsigned value, int bit) {
        mask = BIT(value) | BIT(bit);
        BIT_SET(n, mask);
    }
};
```

Comment: `unsigned bit1:0;` means it is 0 bit large, that does not make sense. Do you mean `unsigned bit1:1;`?

Comment: I think mch is right - `bit1:0` says "use zero bits of the unsigned", where `bit1:1` says "use one bit"

Comment: To avoid some implementation issues use `#define BIT(n) (1u << n)`  (add `u`)

Comment: understand this is not portable in any way...once it works on your compiler today, turn it in call it done, dont do it again...

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious problem is that `:0` means "a bit-field of zero bits" which doesn't make any sense. You should change this to 1 and then you can assign individual bits through code like `the_union.the_struct.bit1 = 1;`.

This format is an alternative to the bit set/clear macros you wrote.

Your union should look like:

```
typedef union
{
  uint16_t word;
  uint8_t  byte[2];
  struct{
     uint16_t bit1:1;
  ...
```

***However***. This is a really bad idea and your teacher should know better than to give such assignments. Bit-fields in C are a bag of worms - they are very poorly specified by the standard. Problems:

- You can't know which bit that is the MSB, it is not defined.
- You can't know if there will be padding bits/bytes somewhere.
- You can't even use `uint16_t` or `uint8_t` because bit-fields are only specified to work with `int`.

And so on. In addition you have to deal with endianness and alignment. See [Why bit endianness is an issue in bitfields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields).

Essentially, code using bit-fields like this will rely heavily on the specific compiler. It will be completely non-portable.

*All* of these problems could be avoided by dropping the bit-field and use  bitwise operators on a `uint16_t` instead, like you did in your macros. With bitwise operators only, your code will turn deterministic and 100% portable. You can even use them to dodge endianess, by using bit shifts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the union definition:

```
union WORD_T
{
    uint16_t word;

    struct
    {
        uint8_t byte0;
        uint8_t byte1;
    };

    struct
    {
        uint8_t bit0:1;
        uint8_t bit1:1;
        uint8_t bit2:1;
        uint8_t bit3:1;
        uint8_t bit4:1;
        uint8_t bit5:1;
        uint8_t bit6:1;
        uint8_t bit7:1;
        uint8_t bit8:1;
        uint8_t bit9:1;
        uint8_t bit10:1;
        uint8_t bit11:1;
        uint8_t bit12:1;
        uint8_t bit13:1;
        uint8_t bit14:1;
        uint8_t bit15:1;
    };
};
```

To assign to the individual components, do something similar to the following:

```
union WORD_T data;

data.word = 0xF0F0; // (3) Assign to entire word

data.byte0 = 0xAA; // (2) Assign to individual byte

data.bit0 = 0; // (1) Assign to individual bits
data.bit1 = 1;
data.bit2 = 1;
data.bit2 = 0;
```

Comment: when would byte1 be used?

Comment: @DouglasAdolph setting byte0 like in my example only overwrites the lower 8 bits of the 16 bit memory location. Use byte1 to set the upper 8 bits of the same 16 bit memory location.