# Rust bitfields and enumerations C++ style

Tags: c++, winapi, rust, bit-fields, bitflags

I'm a Rust beginner which comes from C/C++. To start off I tried to create a simple "Hello-World" like program for Microsoft Windows using [user32.MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx) where I stumbled upon a problem related to bitfields. *Disclaimer: All code snippets were written in the SO editor and might contain errors.*

## MessageBox "Hello-World" in C

The consolidated C declarations needed to call the UTF-16LE version of the function are:

```c
enum MessageBoxResult {
    IDFAILED,
    IDOK,
    IDCANCEL,
    IDABORT,
    IDRETRY,
    IDIGNORE,
    IDYES,
    IDNO,
    IDTRYAGAIN = 10,
    IDCONTINUE
};

enum MessageBoxType {
    // Normal enumeration values.
    MB_OK,
    MB_OKCANCEL,
    MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE,
    MB_YESNOCANCEL,
    MB_YESNO,
    MB_RETRYCANCEL,
    MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE,

    MB_ICONERROR            = 0x10UL,
    MB_ICONQUESTION         = 0x20UL,
    MB_ICONEXCLAMATION      = 0x30UL,
    MB_ICONINFORMATION      = 0x40UL,

    MB_DEFBUTTON1           = 0x000UL,
    MB_DEFBUTTON2           = 0x100UL,
    MB_DEFBUTTON3           = 0x200UL,
    MB_DEFBUTTON4           = 0x300UL,

    MB_APPLMODAL            = 0x0000UL,
    MB_SYSTEMMODAL          = 0x1000UL,
    MB_TASKMODAL            = 0x2000UL,

    // Flag values.
    MB_HELP                 = 1UL << 14,

    MB_SETFOREGROUND        = 1UL << 16,
    MB_DEFAULT_DESKTOP_ONLY = 1UL << 17,
    MB_TOPMOST              = 1UL << 18,
    MB_RIGHT                = 1UL << 19,
    MB_RTLREADING           = 1UL << 20,
    MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION = 1UL << 21
};

MessageBoxResult __stdcall MessageBoxW(
    HWND            hWnd,
    const wchar_t * lpText,
    const wchar_t * lpCaption,
    MessageBoxType  uType
);
```

Usage:

```
MessageBoxType mbType = MB_YESNO | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_DEFBUTTON3 | MB_TOPMOST;
if ((mbType & 0x0F /* All bits for buttons */ == MB_YESNO) && (mbType & 0xF0 /* All bits for icons */ == MB_ICONEXCLAMATION) && (mbType & 0xF00 /* All bits for default buttons */ == MB_DEFBUTTON3) && (mbType & MB_TOPMOST != 0)) {
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Text", L"Title", mbType);
}
```

The `MessageBoxType` enumeration contains enumeration values and flag values. The problem with that is that `MB_DEFBUTTON2` and `MB_DEFBUTTON3` can be used together and "unexpectedly" result in `MB_DEFBUTTON4`. Also the access is quite error prone and ugly, I have to `|`, `&` and shift everything manually when checking for flags in the value.

## MessageBox "Hello-World" in C++

In C++ the same enumeration can be cleverly put into a structure, which has the same size as the enumeration and makes the access way easier, safer and prettier. It makes use of bitfields - [the layout of bitfields not defined by the C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields), but since I only want to use it for x86-Windows it is always the same, so I can rely on it.

```cpp
enum class MessageBoxResult : std::uint32_t {
    Failed,
    Ok,
    Cancel,
    Abort,
    Retry,
    Ignore,
    Yes,
    No,
    TryAgain = 10,
    Continue
};

enum class MessageBoxButton : std::uint32_t {
    Ok,
    OkCancel,
    AbortRetryIgnore,
    YesNoCancel,
    YesNo,
    RetryCancel,
    CancelTryContinue
};

enum class MessageBoxDefaultButton : std::uint32_t {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four
};

// Union so one can access all flags as a value and all boolean values separately.
union MessageBoxFlags {
    enum class Flags : std::uint32_t {
        None,
        Help                = 1UL << 0,
        SetForeground       = 1UL << 2,
        DefaultDesktopOnly  = 1UL << 3,
        TopMost             = 1UL << 4,
        Right               = 1UL << 5,
        RtlReading          = 1UL << 6,
        ServiceNotification = 1UL << 7
    };

    // Flags::operator|, Flags::operator&, etc. omitted here.

    Flags flags;
    struct {
        bool help                   : 1;
        char _padding0              : 1;
        bool setForeground          : 1;
        bool defaultDesktopOnly     : 1;
        bool topMost                : 1;
        bool right                  : 1;
        bool rtlReading             : 1;
        bool serviceNotification    : 1;
        char _padding1              : 8;
        char _padding2              : 8;
        char _padding3              : 8;
    };

    constexpr MessageBoxFlags(const Flags flags = Flags::None)
        : flags(flags) {}
};

enum class MessageBoxIcon : std::uint32_t {
    None,
    Stop,
    Question,
    Exclamation,
    Information
};

enum class MessageBoxModality : std::uint32_t {
    Application,
    System,
    Task
};

union MessageBoxType {
    std::uint32_t value;
    struct {                                          // Used bits                                   Minimum (Base 2)                          Maximum (Base 2)                          Min (Base 16) Max (Base 16)
        MessageBoxButton button                 :  4; // 0000.0000.0000.0000|0000.0000.0000.XXXX     0000.0000.0000.0000|0000.0000.0000.0000 - 0000.0000.0000.0000|0000.0000.0000.0110 : 0x0000.0000 - 0x0000.0006
        MessageBoxIcon icon                     :  4; // 0000.0000.0000.0000|0000.0000.XXXX.0000     0000.0000.0000.0000|0000.0000.0001.0000 - 0000.0000.0000.0000|0000.0000.0100.0000 : 0x0000.0010 - 0x0000.0040
        MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton   :  4; // 0000.0000.0000.0000|0000.XXXX.0000.0000     0000.0000.0000.0000|0000.0001.0000.0000 - 0000.0000.0000.0000|0000.0011.0000.0000 : 0x0000.0100 - 0x0000.0300
        MessageBoxModality modality             :  2; // 0000.0000.0000.0000|00XX.0000.0000.0000     0000.0000.0000.0000|0001.0000.0000.0000 - 0000.0000.0000.0000|0010.0000.0000.0000 : 0x0000.1000 - 0x0000.2000
        MessageBoxFlags::Flags flags            :  8; // 0000.0000.00XX.XXXX|XX00.0000.0000.0000     0000.0000.0000.0000|0100.0000.0000.0000 - 0000.0000.0010.0000|0000.0000.0000.0000 : 0x0000.4000 - 0x0020.0000
        std::uint32_t _padding0                 : 10; // XXXX.XXXX.XX00.0000|0000.0000.0000.0000     
    };

    MessageBoxType(
        const MessageBoxButton button,
        const MessageBoxIcon icon = MessageBoxIcon::None,
        const MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton = MessageBoxDefaultButton::One,
        const MessageBoxModality modality = MessageBoxModality::Application,
        const MessageBoxFlags::Flags flags = MessageBoxFlags::Flags::None
    ) : button(button), icon(icon), defaultButton(defaultButton), modality(modality), flags(flags), _padding0(0) {}

    MessageBoxType() : value(0) {}
};

MessageBoxResult __stdcall MessageBoxW(
    HWND            parentWindow,
    const wchar_t * text,
    const wchar_t * caption,
    MessageBoxType  type
);
```

Usage:

```
auto mbType = MessageBoxType(MessageBoxButton::YesNo, MessageBoxIcon::Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton::Three, MessageBoxModality::Application, MessageBoxFlags::Flags::TopMost);
if (mbType.button == MessageBoxButton::YesNo && mbType.icon == MessageBoxIcon::Exclamation && mbType.defaultButton == MessageBoxDefaultButton::Three && mbType.flags.topMost) {
    MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Text", L"Title", mbType);
}
```

With this C++ version I can access flags as boolean values and have enumeration classes for the other types, all while it still being a simple `std::uint32_t` in memory. Now I struggled to implement this in Rust.

## MessageBox "Hello-World" in Rust

```rust
#[repr(u32)]
enum MessageBoxResult {
    Failed,
    Ok,
    Cancel,
    Abort,
    Retry,
    Ignore,
    Yes,
    No,
    TryAgain = 10,
    Continue
}

#[repr(u32)]
enum MessageBoxButton {
    Ok,
    OkCancel,
    AbortRetryIgnore,
    YesNoCancel,
    YesNo,
    RetryCancel,
    CancelTryContinue
}

#[repr(u32)]
enum MessageBoxDefaultButton {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four
}

#[repr(u32)]
enum MessageBoxIcon {
    None,
    Stop,
    Question,
    Exclamation,
    Information
}

#[repr(u32)]
enum MessageBoxModality {
    Application,
    System,
    Task
}

// MessageBoxFlags and MessageBoxType ?
```

I know about the [WinApi crate](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) which to my understanding is generated automatically from VC++-header files which doesn't help, because I will have the same problems as in C. I also saw the [bitflags macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/bitflags/bitflags/macro.bitflags.html) but it seems to me it doesn't handle this kind of "complexity".

How would I implement `MessageBoxFlags` and `MessageBoxType` in Rust, so I can access it in a nice (not necessarily the same) way as in my C++ implementation?

Comment: Just a small note: `winapi` is *not* generated automatically.  It's transcribed by hand. Every attempt made to bind win32 to Rust automatically has ended in failure, the headers standing triumphant over the bloodied corpses of the conversion programs, their authors broken in mind and spirit.  There's a reason the head of the `winapi` project is a rabbit.

Comment: To be slightly more on-topic: I wouldn't bother trying to do this via unions and bitflags.  I don't think the `bitflags` crate was designed for this level of contortion.  I'd just write getters/setters on a `#[repr(C)] struct MessageBoxFlags(u8);`.

Comment: Did you see the crate [bitfield](https://docs.rs/bitfield/0.12.1/bitfield/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [bitfield](https://docs.rs/bitfield/0.12.1/bitfield/) crate @Boiethios mentioned is kind of what I wanted. I created my own first macro crate [bitfield](https://github.com/MauriceKayser/rs-bitfield) which allows me to write the following:

```rust
#[bitfield::bitfield(32)]
struct Styles {
    #[field(size = 4)] button: Button,
    #[field(size = 4)] icon: Icon,
    #[field(size = 4)] default_button: DefaultButton,
    #[field(size = 2)] modality: Modality,
    style: Style
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, bitfield::Flags)]
#[repr(u8)]
enum Style {
    Help = 14,
    Foreground = 16,
    DefaultDesktopOnly,
    TopMost,
    Right,
    RightToLeftReading,
    ServiceNotification
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, bitfield::Field)]
#[repr(u8)]
enum Button {
    Ok,
    OkCancel,
    AbortRetryIgnore,
    YesNoCancel,
    YesNo,
    RetryCancel,
    CancelTryContinue
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, bitfield::Field)]
#[repr(u8)]
enum DefaultButton {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, bitfield::Field)]
#[repr(u8)]
enum Icon {
    None,
    Stop,
    Question,
    Exclamation,
    Information
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, bitfield::Field)]
#[repr(u8)]
enum Modality {
    Application,
    System,
    Task
}
```

I can then use the code like this:

```rust
// Verbose:
let styles = Styles::new()
    .set_button(Button::CancelTryContinue)
    .set_icon(Icon::Exclamation)
    .set_style(Style::Foreground, true)
    .set_style(Style::TopMost, true);

// Alternatively:
let styles = Styles::new() +
    Button::CancelTryContinue +
    Icon::Exclamation +
    Style::Foreground +
    Style::TopMost;

let result = user32::MessageBoxW(/* ... */, styles);
```