# Assigning unsigned short to an unsigned char bit field makes STM32F1 reset

Tags: c++, bit-fields, iar, stm32f1

So I came across this issue without understing why.

I'm reading an EEPROM portion of 16 bit. On the first ever read of the EEPROM, all the cells are 0xffff. This portion of memory will store a flag so, basically 1 bit.

This flag is stored into the code inside a structure as `unsigned char maxM1 :1;`. See below

```
struct s_system {
   unsigned char maxM1 :1;
}
```

I'm reading the EEPROM with a special function `rd_word(MEMORY_ADDRESS)` that returns 16bit

Now I'm assigning the return value to the `maxM1` variable quoted above as

```
struct s_system sys;
...
...
sys.maxM1=rd_word(MEMORY_ADDRESS);
```

Where `rd_word` returns `return SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI2);`

Now, I'm using IAR 6.50 as IDE and in debug mode it seems that the line `sys.maxM1=rd_word(MEMORY_ADDRESS);` makes the STM32F to reset

Now, I'm thinking it's because I'm assigning a value not compatible to the variable type of the variable but, in this case, shouldn't the compiler be reporting an error?

Comment: You could try: `sys.maxM1=rd_word(MEMORY_ADDRESS) != 0;` or similar.

Comment: @PaulSanders yeah we worked it around with another variable of the same type and checking if it's `>1` but I would like to know why it happens and if it's because my theory or not

Comment: Not sure, please show the signature of `rd_word`.

Comment: @PaulSanders actually it returns the data in the DR register as I read the EEPROM via serial communication so the `rd_word` use `SPI_I2S_SendData` to send the data to read and `SPI_I2S_ReceiveData` to receive it

Comment: OK.  I'm not familiar with the stm32 so I don't know what it's actually up to there.  But it sounds like you might be writing out of bounds if you directly assign that to a bitfield (call that a compiler bug if you like).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever used bit fields, but did some research now. The most useful information was here:

[Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52476692/5932454), Andrew's answer, which I will quote

> Appendix D.4 of MISRA C:2012 is usefully titled "The essential types
> of bit fields"
>
> - For a bit-field which is implemented with an essentially Boolean    type, it is essentially Boolean
> - For a bit-field which is    implemented with a signed type, it is the    Signed Type of Lowest Rank    which is able to represent the
>   bit    field
> - For a bit-field which is    implemented with a unsigned type, it is    the Unsigned Type of Lowest    Rank which is able to represent the
>   bit field
>
> The Unsigned Type of Lowest Rank of a single-bit unsigned integer
> would be uint8_t (aka unsigned char) - assuming that the tool does not
> interpret a single-bit as being boolean...

Further down he states that for a single-bit field you should get away with casting it to uint8_t (aka unsigned char).

My personal guess is that something goes bits up because of byte/halfword access because you don't explicitly cast your 16-bit uint.

Since the struct takes full 8 bits anyway, a conceptually simpler and safer idea might be to have a byte variable in the struct and enum or a set of defines associated with every position of every bit field in that byte, and you can do bitwise operations using those defines when writing there or reading from there, much like fiddling directly with peripheral registers. It will probably generate the same machine code, since, well, if you need to write only one bit to the byte, you kinda need to read it out, flip one bit and write it back anyway, because, you know, byte access.