# Is assignment of bit field with different Endianness implementation specific

Tags: c++, c, endianness, bit-fields

As we know, we have two types of Endianness: big endian and little endian.

Let's say that an integer takes 4 bytes, so the layout of the integer `1` should be **0x01** 0x00 0x00 0x00 for little endian and **0x00** 0x00 0x00 0x01 for big endian.

To check if a machine is little endian or big endian, we can code as below:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    char *p = (char *)&a;
    // *p == 1 means little endian, otherwise, big endian

    return 0;
}
```

As my understanding, `*p` is assigned with the first octet: `0x01` for little endian and `0x00` for big endian (the two bold parts above), that's how the code works.

Now I don't quite understand how bit field works with different Endianness.

Let's say we have such a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char a1 : 1;
    unsigned char a2 : 1;
    unsigned char a6 : 3;
}Bbit;
```

And we do the assignment as below:

```
Bbit bit;
bit.a1 = 1;
bit.a2 = 1;
```

Will this piece of code be implementation specific? I'm asking if the values of `bit.a1` and of `bit.a2` are `1` on little endian and are `0` on big endian? Or are they definitely `1` regardless of the different Endianness?

Comment: The layout of bitfields is implementation-defined.  The bits can really go anywhere the compiler wants them.

Comment: "Let's say that an integer takes 4 bytes" --> Interesting one is concerned about various endians, yet not various `int` sizes.

Comment: There is much implementation defined issues with bit-fields.  "A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type." so even OP's `unsigned char a1 : 1;` lacks portability.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica God please don't tell me various `int` sizes matter while assigning a bit field...

Comment: If you assigned the value `1` to `bit.a2`, why would the value of `bit.a2` be something other than `1`?

Comment: Simplification: bit-field ≠ high portability.  Bit-fields good for mapping hardware registers. Else consider `uintN_t` and shifts/masks and trust your compiler to optimize.

Comment: @Yves Bit-fields are a place in C where `int` might differ from `signed int` --> "it is
implementation-defined whether the specifier int designates the same type as signed int or the same type as unsigned int."  `int a1 : 1;` might encode -1,0 or 0,1.

Comment: @JaMiT Well, in fact, this is what I'm asking. As you see, an integer contains four octets, I don't know which octet will be used to assign to `bit.a2`. If it's always the first octet, obviously, the first octet of little endian is `0x01` but the first octet of big endian is `0x00`.

Comment: "we have two types of Endianness:" --> Could not resist: [PDP-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#PDP-endian).

Comment: @Yves Why does it matter which octet stores the bits of `bit.a2`? The statement `bit.a2 = 1;` assigns the value `1` to the bit called `a2`. It does **not** assign the value `1` to the entire `unsigned char` nor to the entire struct. The only bits that are affected are the ones associated with that bit field (which in this case is a single bit).

Comment: Re "*`// *p == 1 means little endian, otherwise, big endian`*", This is incorrect. There are more than two different endian-ness.

Comment: @JaMiT You see, the size of `bit.a2` is one bit, whereas the size of `1` is 32 bits, right? So when we assign `1` to `bit.a2`, which bit in that 32 bits will be used to assign to `bit.a2`?

Comment: @Vves - That doesn't matter.    The assignment `bit.a1 = x` does not pick one of the bits of `x` and use that to set the value of `bit.a1`.    `bit.a1` can represent the values `0` or `1`.    One of those values is `1`.    So `bit.a1 = 1` will set `bit.a1` to `1`, not to `0`.

Comment: @Peter Well, If `bit.a1` definitely equals to `1` regardless of the different endianness, why did people say that bit-field != high protability?

Comment: @Yves - because there is more to portability than the question of whether `bit.a1 = 1` will set `bit.a1` to be equal to `1`.  A lot of code that fiddles bits embeds unstated assumptions about the layout of `bit`  (e.g. whether `bit.a1` and `bit.a2` are adjacent bits, or if there is padding between them).   Different compilers (or even compilation options) can change the layout of `bit` - so code that relies on the layout being the *same* will malfunction.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why bit endianness is an issue in bitfields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043483/why-bit-endianness-is-an-issue-in-bitfields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char a1 : 1;
    unsigned char a2 : 1;
    unsigned char a6 : 3;
}Bbit;
```

and a definition:

```
Bbit byte;
```

Suppose `byte` is stored in a single byte and is currently zeroed out: `0000 0000`.

```
byte.a1 = 1;
```

This sets the bit called `a1` to `1`. If `a1` is the first bit, then `byte` has become `1000 0000`, but if `a1` is the fifth bit, then `byte` has become `0000 1000`, and if `a1` is the eighth bit, then `byte` has become `0000 0001`.

```
byte.a2 = 1;
```

This sets the bit called `a2` to `1`. If `a2` is the second bit, then `byte` has (likely) become `1100 0000`, but if `a2` is the sixth bit, then `byte` has (likely) become `0000 1100`, and if `a2` is the seventh bit, then `byte` has become `0000 0011`. (These are only "likely" because there is no guarantee that the bits follow some reasonable order. It's just unlikely that a compiler will go out of its way to mess up this example.)

Endianness is not a factor when it comes to the values that are stored. Only the bits representing the specified bit-field are changed with each assignment, and the value being assigned is reduced to that number of bits (with implementation-defined behavior if that value is too big for that number of bits).

Comment: Using `unsigned char` as the bitfield underlying type is non-portable as well,  the only types guaranteed to be supported are `_Bool`, `signed int` and `unsigned int`

Answer (score 2):

With bitfields, not only is byte endianness implementation defined but so is bit endianness.

Section 6.7.2.1p11 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding structs states:

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field.  If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit.  If insufficient space remains,whether  a  bit-field  that  does  not  fit  is  put  into  the  next  unit  or  overlaps  adjacent  units  is implementation-defined.  The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order  or  low-order  to  high-order)  is  implementation-defined.  The  alignment  of  the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

So the compiler is free to reorder bitfields in a struct as it sees fit.  As an example of this, here is the struct that represents an IP header in /usr/include/netinet/ip.h on Linux:

```
struct iphdr
  {
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    unsigned int ihl:4;
    unsigned int version:4;
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned int version:4;
    unsigned int ihl:4;
#else
# error "Please fix <bits/endian.h>"
#endif
    u_int8_t tos;
    u_int16_t tot_len;
    u_int16_t id;
    u_int16_t frag_off;
    u_int8_t ttl;
    u_int8_t protocol;
    u_int16_t check;
    u_int32_t saddr;
    u_int32_t daddr;
    /*The options start here. */
  };
```

Here you can see that there are two fields which are bitfields, and the order in which they are declared depends on the endianness in use.

So what this means is that you can't depend on any particular byte (or bit) ordering if you send a raw struct over a network.

Given your example with some additions to view the representation:

```
Bbit bit;
bit.a1 = 1;
bit.a2 = 1;
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&bit;
printf("%02x\n", *p);
```

A big endian system will probably print `a0` while a little endian system will probably print `03`.  And that's assuming the unused bits happen to be set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not even require that the bytes representing an integer must be in big-endian order or little-endian order (they may be mixed) let alone what order bit-fields are in. These things are implementation-defined, which means the C standard does not specify them but requires they be documented in the compiler manual or other documentation. The order of bit-fields in bytes or other units does not have to match the order of bytes in objects.

Comment: C11 6.7.2.1/11 does seem to say that the next bit-field must be in adjacent bits to the previous field (unless insufficient space remains in the unit), and they must be in consistent order (be it low-high or high-low),  I assume that is meant to be interpreted in context of the logical order of the bits, regardless of byte endianness

Comment: @M.M "a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure" to me is addressing bit-fields as they are defined in source code and "packed into adjacent bits" does not imply any order, it only specifies "adjacent".

Comment: @AndrewHenle: If a is adjacent to b and b is adjacent to c, you must have abc or cba. It cannot be acb. So the bit-fields must be in ascending or descending order in the logical ordering of bits in the storage unit used for them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  I don't read 6.7.2.1p11 that strictly.  I see no requirement for a consistent ordering. An implementation that decides to split bit-fields defined in source as abcde  would still be conforming if it placed the fields in cba in one unit and then de in the next.  I see nothing in "The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined." that requires consistency from unit to unit, however nonsensical such an implementation might seem.