# casting 115bit data to union of bitfields gets erroneous results

Tags: c++, endianness, unions, bit-fields

I'm trying to cast a 115bit data to a union of bitfields and getting a wrong result.

#### Setup

I have two types of data:

```
Configuration: data[62:0]
               addr[113:107]
               type[114]

RawBits:       lowBits[63:0]
               highBits[115:64]
```

So I defined the following bitfields and union:

```
typedef struct RawBits {
  unsigned long int lowBits:64;
  unsigned long int highBits:51;
  unsigned long int reserved :13;
} __attribute__((packed))rawBits;

typedef struct Configuration {
  unsigned long int data : 62;
  unsigned long int addr : 7;
  unsigned long int type : 1;
  unsigned long int reserved : 58;
} __attribute__((packed))Configuration ;

typedef union Instruction {
  RawBits bits;
  Configuration configuration;
} __attribute__((packed))Instruction;
```

As data I used:

```
uint8_t configuration_test[] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xfc,
                                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xfc, 0x00,
```

And to convert the buffer to the union type I used simple casting:

```
Instruction *instruction = (Instruction *)configuration_test;
```

#### Expected result

```
instruction->bits->lowBits  = 0xfffffffffffffffc
instruction->bits->highBits = 0x00000000000001fc
instruction->bits->reserved = 0x0000000000000000

instruction->configuration->data     = 0x3fffffffffffffff
instruction->configuration->addr     = 0x000000000000007f
instruction->configuration->type     = 0x0000000000000000
instruction->configuration->reserved = 0x0000000000000000
```

#### Real result

```
instruction->bits->lowBits  = 0xfcffffffffffffff
instruction->bits->highBits = 0x0004010000000000
instruction->bits->reserved = 0x000000000000001f

instruction->configuration->data     = 0x3cffffffffffffff
instruction->configuration->addr     = 0x0000000000000003
instruction->configuration->type     = 0x0000000000000000
instruction->configuration->reserved = 0x0003f00400000000
```

Comment: The compiler is free to represent bitfields in any way it chooses.  The moment you chose to type pun that array as a `Instruction` is the moment your program's behavior became undefined...  or at least implementation-specific.

Comment: Which compiler and version do you use?

Comment: @paddy i need the bitfield to represent hw registers, so it need to be tightly packed

Comment: @trylimits i'm using gcc version 7.5.0

Comment: A bitfield can't "straddle" integers – `Configuration` is larger than you think. Use bitmasks and shifting.

Comment: Looks like a little-endian byte order took place. Bitfields use the hardware byte order, not the network byte order.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6044223/580083