# Changing bits in flag words on unknown mask

Tags: c++, casting, bit-fields

Because layout of bit fields is implementation-dependent I am looking for alternative to [C struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68501427/split-string-into-struct-without-knowing-structure). wikipedia suggests to emulate bit fields with [bit operators](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

Let's assume we have incoming integer variable with unknown value (range 0-7). Before the value can be set as WIDTH it must be shifted `var << 2` according to it's bit field declaration. Furthermore to ensure variable out of range is not overlapping foreign bits `var &= ~224` must deleted from left.

```
#define BOLD        0b00000001
#define ITALIC      0b00000010
#define WIDTH       0b00011100
#define HEIGHT      0b11100000

unsigned char flagword = 0;
unsigned int intvar = 7;
```

How can we determine unknown shift count of previous declared variable bit masks?
How to cast integer into desired bit position with C style bit shift or C++ std::bitset?

```
// desired function C/C++
void setBit( unsigned char * byte, unsigned char bitmask, unsigned int value ) {
  unsigned char bitfield = *byte;
  if ( value ) {
    /* determine shift count from bitmask
       cast + shift int
       set bits
    */
    bitfield |= bitmask;
  }
  else
    // delete bits
    bitfield &= ~bitmask;
  *byte = bitfield;
}

// desired function call
setBit( &flagword, WIDTH, intvar );
```

Note: This is not a homework

Comment: std::countr_zero and std::countl_zero can give you the indices of the bits in the mask ( if they are contiguous).

Comment: unfortunately that requires <bit> which is not available so ended up with function https://stackoverflow.com/q/56320733